# Network connection lost with iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ssl, nsurlconnection, ios4

I am sending SOAP request from my iPhone app.It is working well on all versions of iOS except iOS4.3. Web service is secured and taking credentials, I am provide it through code. It works on iOS4.2 also, but getting network time out error on iOS4.3.

Anyone has solution how to solve this? I also searched on google didnt get anything.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed. Apple has released iOS 4.3.1 and it fixes all authentication bugs.Its working with iOS 4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't make sense for that to happen. You should make sure that you have internet connectivity on that device and that the device is not using some incorrect DNS server (could be if you had manually set up your wifi connection).

Comment: I have checked wifi its working....Even web service without credentials(without username and password) are working fine on iOS 4.3. Only problem is getting on secured webservice for iOS4.3

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a particular SOAP library? I ask because I know that the SOAP code generated by the latest release version of wsdl2objc has a 4.3 specific bug that impacts any date fields in the response, it has been fixed in trunk, but it caught us out when moving from 4.2

This wouldn't cause the symptoms you describe, however it might give you somewhere to start looking.

So some more detail on what third party libraries you are using could help (eg ASIHTTPRequest / wsdl2objc etc) ...